# Adding an item to a List when clicking a WebPart Properties 'OK' button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-web-part

I have a superb Web Part downloaded from Codeplex which essentially is a Countdown Timer in jQuery. (spCountdown) The code itself works perfectly, however I want to tweak it, in what I thought would be a relatively easy thing to do.

In the Web Part properties of the solution, there is a textbox where you enter the Date/Time which you wish to set the countdown timer. When I click 'OK' to submit the WebPart, I would like the date value in the textbox to be added to a List as a new List item. I've got the code to add the List item (or what I think is the correct code) but what I can't do is get the function to execute when the WebPart 'OK' button is clicked.

Now, I have downloaded the source code which is available but I can't fathom how to hook the 'Update List Item' code onto the onclick event of the button (as I can't find an onclick event!).

**My code to add the date to the new List:**

```
// create item in Deadline Configuration List
        using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["DLConfig"];
                SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items.Add();
                oListItem["Title"] = "Deadline Date";
                oListItem["TaskDueDate"] = new DateTime(WebPart.TargetDate.Year, WebPart.TargetDate.Month, WebPart.TargetDate.Day);
                oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                oListItem.Update();
            }
        }
```

**Original WebPart Code:**

*SPCountdownWebpart.cs*

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace SPCountdown.SPCountdownWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class SPCountdownWebPart : WebPart
    {
        // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/SPCountdown/SPCountdownWebPart/SPCountdownWebPartUserControl.ascx";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            var control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            if (control != null)
            {
                ((SPCountdownWebPartUserControl)control).WebPart = this;
            }
            Controls.Add(control);
        }


        [Category("Countdown Settings"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Target Date/Time"),
        WebDescription("Please enter the target date/time for countdown.")]
        public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }


    }
}
```

*SPCountdownWebpartUserControl.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace SPCountdown.SPCountdownWebPart
{
    public partial class SPCountdownWebPartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public SPCountdownWebPart WebPart { get; set; }

        public SPCountdownWebPartUserControl()
        {
            PreRender += SPCountdownWebPartUserControl_PreRender;
        }

        void SPCountdownWebPartUserControl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // parse date from properties
            var targetDateString = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Year,
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Month - 1, //uses 0-based index
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Day,
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Hour,
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Minute,
                                                 WebPart.TargetDate.Second);

            // js sources
            const string jqueryScript = "<script type='text/javascript' src='/_layouts/SPCountdown/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>";
            const string countdownScript = "<script type='text/javascript' src='/_layouts/SPCountdown/js/jquery.countdown.min.js'></script>";

            // create javascript implementing countdown
            const string jsCountdownFormat = "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function () {{var targetDate = new Date({0});$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({{until: targetDate}});}});</script>";
            var jsCountdown = string.Format(jsCountdownFormat, targetDateString);

            // register client scripts
            var cs = Page.ClientScript;

            if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jQuery"))
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    GetType(),
                    "jQuery",
                    jqueryScript);

            if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jsCountdownScript"))
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    GetType(),
                    "jsCountdownScript",
                    countdownScript);

            if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jsCountdown"))
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                    GetType(),
                    "jsCountdown",
                    jsCountdown);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Can anyone help me with where I need to implement my code to get the List Item to be created when the Web Part properties are set?

Answer (score 0):

You can add that feature by changing the below

```
private DateTime _targetDate;

[Category("Countdown Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Target Date/Time"),
WebDescription("Please enter the target date/time for countdown.")]
public DateTime TargetDate { 
    get { return _targetDate; }
    set { 
        _targetDate = value;
        //CODE TO INSERT NEW LIST ITEM GOES HERE
}
```